# select2 : modify the title of li with value of option

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm looking for a solution with select2, to automaticatly insert the value of option :

```
<select multiple>

    <option value="1" selected >Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3" selected >Option 3</option>

</select>
```

Into the title (or a data-element) of the li selected :

```
<li class="select2-selection__choice" title="Option 3"></li>
<li class="select2-selection__choice" title="Option 1"></li>
```

I want to use the title attribute because i use the sortable function to keep visual order of drag and drop.

I search a solution for a week...

Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: what version of select2? [This issue](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3158) shows how you can remove a title in v4 so I presume the same could be used to add a title

Comment: When i use select2 on select tag, the li tag for display have a title with the content of option tag. I want to automatically replace content of the title in li tag with the value of option tag who correspond. (sorry for my english is not my first language)

Comment: My version is Select2 4.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your issue. You just need to add title to your options like

```
<option value="2" title="2">Option 2</option>
```